# EF6 Update-Database is attempting to create a column that would duplicate an existing computed column

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have some computed columns in a SQL database that're giving EF6 a good bit of trouble. I'm using [this technique](https://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2012/09/23/calculated-columns-in-entity-framework-code-first-migrations.aspx).

For some reason, the PM command `Update-Database` insists on trying to add a column to a table that already exists as a computed column.

I only discovered this by temporarily enabling Automatic Migrations. With Automatic Migrations disabled, I get the famously obscure *"Unable to update database to match the current model because there are pending changes and automatic migration is disabled."*

Here's the relevant excerpted SQL output from `Update-Database -Verbose`:

```
Applying explicit migration: 201805012255477_001.
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LogEntries] (
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [ReceiveTime] [datetime] NOT NULL DEFAULT '1753-01-01T00:00:00.000',
    [SendTime] [datetime] NOT NULL DEFAULT '1753-01-01T00:00:00.000',
    [LogTime] [datetime] NOT NULL DEFAULT '1753-01-01T00:00:00.000',
    [Scale] [real] NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    [Co] [real] NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    [O2] [real] NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.LogEntries] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
)

...

ALTER TABLE [LogEntries] ADD [CorrectionFactor] AS (13.9 / (20.9 - [O2])) PERSISTED

...

Applying automatic migration: 201901160207184_AutomaticMigration.
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[LogEntries] ADD [CorrectionFactor] [real] NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Column names in each table must be unique. Column name 'CorrectionFactor' in table 'dbo.LogEntries' is specified more than once.
```

(Note that I've created no migration named `AutomaticMigration`. EF6 seems to be doing this on its own.)

It's worth mentioning that both the database and the table are created successfully. This problem doesn't occur until after my last migration has run.

**Expected result**

The `Update-Database` command should complete without error

**Actual result**

The `Update-Database` command attempts to create the duplicate column, resulting in a database error

**Things I've tried**

1. Use Data Annotations instead of Fluent API, in case of an obscure bug in EF6
2. Delete the database entirely, so as to start from scratch
3. Double-check all migrations (and supporting code) for accuracy
4. Exclude all migrations from the project and generate a new one
5. Add the `.Ignore()` API; however, that and the `.HasDatabaseGeneratedOption()` API are mutually exclusive

The `.HasDatabaseGeneratedOption()` API appears to have no effect. What else can be done to instruct EF6 to not attempt to create that column?

Here's my code:

**Context**

```
Namespace Db
  Public Class Context
    Inherits DbContext

    Public Sub New()
      MyBase.New(Utils.DbConnectionString)
    End Sub

    Private Sub New(Connection As DbConnection)
      MyBase.New(Connection, True)

      Database.SetInitializer(New CreateDatabaseIfNotExists(Of Context))
      Database.SetInitializer(New MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion(Of Context, Migrations.Configuration))

      Me.Database.Initialize(False)
    End Sub

    Public Shared Function Create() As Context
      Return New Context(DbConnection)
    End Function

    Private Shared ReadOnly Property DbConnection As SqlConnection
      Get
        Return New SqlConnection(Utils.DbConnectionString)
      End Get
    End Property

    Protected Overrides Sub OnModelCreating(Builder As DbModelBuilder)
      Builder.Configurations.AddFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly)
      MyBase.OnModelCreating(Builder)
    End Sub

    Public Property LogEntries As DbSet(Of LogEntry)
  End Class
End Namespace
```

**Entity**

```
Namespace Db
  Public Class LogEntry
    Public Property Id As Integer
    Public Property ReceiveTime As Date
    Public Property SendTime As Date
    Public Property LogTime As Date
    Public Property Scale As Single
    Public Property Scc As Single
    Public Property Co As Single
    Public Property O2 As Single

#Region " Computed Columns "

    Public Property CorrectionFactor As Single
      Get
        Return 13.9 / (20.9 - Me.O2)
      End Get
      Private Set(Value As Single) : End Set
    End Property

    Public Property MinutesOffline As Single
      Get
        Return IIf(Me.Scale < 1, 1, 0)
      End Get
      Private Set(Value As Single) : End Set
    End Property

    Public Property OffsetTime As Date
      Get
        Return Me.LogTime.AddHours(-7)
      End Get
      Private Set(Value As Date) : End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Co7Online As Single
      Get
        Return IIf(Me.Scale > 1, Me.Co7, 0)
      End Get
      Private Set(Value As Single) : End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Shift As Short
      Get
        Return IIf(Me.OffsetTime.Hour < 12, 1, 2)
      End Get
      Private Set(Value As Short) : End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Co7 As Single
      Get
        Return Me.Co * Me.CorrectionFactor
      End Get
      Private Set(Value As Single) : End Set
    End Property

#End Region

  End Class
End Namespace
```

**Configuration**

```
Namespace Configurations
  Public Class LogEntry
    Inherits EntityTypeConfiguration(Of Db.LogEntry)

    Public Sub New()
      Me.Property(Function(Entry) Entry.ReceiveTime).IsRequired()
      Me.Property(Function(Entry) Entry.SendTime).IsRequired()
      Me.Property(Function(Entry) Entry.LogTime).IsRequired()
      Me.Property(Function(Entry) Entry.Scale).IsRequired()
      Me.Property(Function(Entry) Entry.Scc).IsRequired()
      Me.Property(Function(Entry) Entry.Co).IsRequired()
      Me.Property(Function(Entry) Entry.O2).IsRequired()

      Me.HasIndex(Function(Entry) Entry.ReceiveTime).HasName("IX_LogEntries_ReceiveTime")
      Me.HasIndex(Function(Entry) Entry.SendTime).HasName("IX_LogEntries_SendTime")
      Me.HasIndex(Function(Entry) Entry.LogTime).HasName("IX_LogEntries_LogTime")
      Me.HasIndex(Function(Entry) Entry.Scale).HasName("IX_LogEntries_Scale")
      Me.HasIndex(Function(Entry) Entry.Scc).HasName("IX_LogEntries_Scc")
      Me.HasIndex(Function(Entry) Entry.Co).HasName("IX_LogEntries_Co")
      Me.HasIndex(Function(Entry) Entry.O2).HasName("IX_LogEntries_O2")

      Me.Property(Function(Entry) Entry.CorrectionFactor).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)
      Me.Property(Function(Entry) Entry.MinutesOffline).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)
      Me.Property(Function(Entry) Entry.OffsetTime).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)
      Me.Property(Function(Entry) Entry.Co7Online).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)
      Me.Property(Function(Entry) Entry.Shift).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)
      Me.Property(Function(Entry) Entry.Co7).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)
    End Sub
  End Class
End Namespace
```